# Is VHDL default signal assignment also necessary for variables?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I understand that default signal assignment is useful (even necessary) in VHDL to avoid incomplete assignment and inferred latches. I can't discover whether it is also necessary for variables.

Consider this block of code:

```
  test_sequencer : process(fpga_clock)
    variable sequencer_count : unsigned(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  begin
    if rising_edge(fpga_clock) then
      start_writing   <= start_writing;
      start_reading   <= start_reading;
      sequencer_count := sequencer_count; -- is this line necessary
      if not_every_fpga_clock = '1' then
        case sequencer_count is
          when x"4" =>
            start_writing <= '1';
          when x"12" =>
            start_reading <= '1';
          when others =>
            null;
        end case;
        if sequencer_count /= 15 then
          sequencer_count := sequencer_count + 1;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
```

Is the line marked "is this line necessary?" required? I understand that it must be there if `sequencer_count` is a signal. Is it necessary when `sequencer_count` is a variable?

Comment: You're getting answers for some aspects of your multiple distinct questions. In simulation signal identity assignment with no change in value won't generate an event (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 14.7.3.4 Signal update), a variable has a single current value (6.4.2.4 Variable declarations), identity assignment is disregarded in synthesis (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, RTL Synthesis, withdrawn, 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list "By default, the effect of an identity assignment of the signal (or variable) shall be as though the assignment was not present.").

Comment: What is the implication of your comment? Is it a further argurment that identity assignments have no value? Or are you saying that is some cases there is a reason to use an identity assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, default assignments only prevent latches if no clock is present - ie: combinational logic.

Within register/flip-flop logic (code following the "if rising_edge(clock)"),  default assignments prevent hold conditions - which are a normal part of register logic.   A latch will never be produced from code under an "if rising_edge(clock)".

OTOH, what you have I call identity assignment:

```
  start_writing   <= start_writing;
  start_reading   <= start_reading;
  sequencer_count := sequencer_count;
```

Identity assignments are not default assignments and specify feedback explicitly.   These do not prevent latches in combinational logic.

A default assignment assigns either a literal value or a value from the output of a combinational logic signal:

```
  start_writing   <= '0';
  sequencer_count := "0000";
  LedState <= LedNext;
```

Note that for a variable declaration in a process, the initialization is only run when the process is elaborated - which is at the start of time and not each time when the process runs:

```
variable sequencer_count : unsigned(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

This is different from subprogram execution that creates and initializes the variables each time it is called.

Comment: Your answer has helped my understanding. Do the identity assignments have any value at all? If a signal or variable is set in the `if rising_edge(clock)` clause, will it be a latch anyway and that is sufficient to define the behaviour and the identify assignment is redundant. This is what I understand from the other two answers.

Comment: The only time an identity assignment has value is when it overrides a previous setting (done in the same process).   I have never had any occasion to use this.

Comment: Is there any good reason to define an explicit feedback (like what you call an identity assignment, or an `else` clause like in `if rising_edge(clock) then signal <= … else signal <= signal;`)? Does that change the intrinsic function at all, or does it affect the synthesis in any ways?

Comment: I have seen no benefit to using an identity assignment.   As an `else` to an `if rising_edge(Clk)`, it is unlikely that a synthesis tool will support it.   Also from a simulation standpoint, it is an extra, unnecessary action that does not need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

In a synchronous process, with `rising_edge(fpga_clock)`, there is no need for neither default variable assignment nor default signal assignment, and both will hold the value before the rising clock, if there is no new assignment when the process triggers (execute) as a result of the rising clock.

What you may have in mind with respect to inferred latches, is maybe related to a combinatorial process, where a latch can be inferred if some branches of an `if` statement does not assign to a driven signal, like:

```
process (d, en, q)
begin
    if en = '1' then
        q <= d;
    end if;
end process;
```

In this case `q` is only updated if `en` is `'1'`, so a latch is inferred to hold the value of `q` if `en` is `'0'`.

As a related comment, it is often bad coding style to use variables to hold state in a sequential (clocked) process, and better to declare a signal for `sequencer_count`.  Reason is that coding style is then the same for all flip-flops, and it is easier to debug since variables are not viewable in typical simulation waveforms.

Answer (score 2):

None of these lines are necessary:

```
  start_writing   <= start_writing;
  start_reading   <= start_reading;
  sequencer_count := sequencer_count; -- is this line necessary
```

None of them do anything at all. In complete assignment and latch inference is only a problem with combination logic. This is (synchronous) sequential logic. You never need to worry about complete assignment with (synchronous) sequential logic.

Why is this? Well, in the case of combinational logic, if you don't have complete assignment, there will be some combination of inputs that results in a path through the process being followed in which an output of the process (a signal driven by it) does not get assigned a value. Any signal will keep its value until a new value is assigned. Therefore, in the case of incomplete assignment, it will be necessary for the resulting circuit to remember (to store) the state of that output. Therefore, some kind of circuit that can store information will be synthesised. That will not be a flip-flop, because there are no clocks, no `rising_edge` function calls etc; instead, latches will be synthesised to do that remembering. That is doubly bad, because (a) latches are fundamentally bad anyway and (b) your were wanting combinational logic but got sequential. That's a bug.

However, in a (synchronous) sequential circuit, you already have storage. Flip-flops can be considered as 1-bit memories. Therefore, you don't need to ever worry about complete assignment in a (synchronous) sequential process. You are expecting the resulting circuit to be able to store things.